# If stomata is closed at night ,how does exchange of oxygen take place at night?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, respiration

In this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4326751/) in the second paragraph, it is written that the stomata remains closed at night to reduce water loss. We know that the plants respire and take in oxygen at night. Then how do plants take in oxygen i.e. respiration takes place at night?

Again in this [article](https://www.toppr.com/guides/science/respiration-in-organism/respiration-in-plants/), it is written that the oxygen during respiration is taken through stomata. Which is correct ??

Comment: What does the bar-graph in the first article show about the gaseous exchange at the "closed" stomata?

Comment: I can't see where it's written ''closed at night to prevent water loss''? Article is very clear, that stomata closes due to extreme conditions faced by plants. suggest to read it again.

Comment: It's clearly written " In leaves, they typically open during the day to favor CO2 diffusion when light is available for photosynthesis, and close at night to limit transpiration and save water". Please read the second paragraph's second line properly..

Comment: I recommend looking at figure 1 here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4940480/. Plants don't run out of O2 overnight, they can store it!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what's written in the article, stomata typically close at night as there's no sunlight so no photosynthesis. Respiration however continues 24/7 but the rates vary. During the night, the rate of respiration drops since stomata are closed. But it never drops to 0. Respiration still happens as oxygen exchange can still be done through the following three routes:

. Direct diffusion of oxygen through the waxy cuticle in minute amounts
. There are small pores in the stem region called lenticels which allow the exchange of oxygen
. Some small open spaces left in the stomata even after the closure of stomata

Here's a link for reference: [https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Book%3A_Biology_(Kimball)/16%3A_The_Anatomy_and_Physiology_of_Plants/16.02%3A_Plant_Physiology/16.2D%3A_Gas_Exchange_in_Plants#:~:text=the%20plasma%20membrane.-,Leaves,stomata%20(singular%20%3D%20stoma).&text=Normally%20stomata%20open%20when%20the,and%20close%20during%20the%20night](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Book%3A_Biology_(Kimball)/16%3A_The_Anatomy_and_Physiology_of_Plants/16.02%3A_Plant_Physiology/16.2D%3A_Gas_Exchange_in_Plants#:%7E:text=the%20plasma%20membrane.-,Leaves,stomata%20(singular%20%3D%20stoma).&text=Normally%20stomata%20open%20when%20the,and%20close%20during%20the%20night).

Hope it helps.